# error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im getting this error

error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

I cant figure out whats wrong. I am pretty sure I have everything set up correctly

```js
var x = true;

function openNav() {
  if (x == true) {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    x = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";

  }

}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 250px;
  /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed;
  /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: ;
  /* 0 to Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidebar */
}
```

```html
<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Toggle Sidebar</button>
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Auto &amp; Vehicale</a>
  <a href="#">Beuty &amp; Fashion</a>
  <a href="#">Comedy</a>
  <a href="#">Education</a>
  <a href="#">Entertainment</a>
  <a href="#">Film &amp; Animation</a>
  <a href="#">Food</a>
  <a href="#">Gaming</a>
  <a href="#">How-To</a>
  <a href="#">Music</a>
  <a href="#">News &amp; Politics</a>
  <a href="#">Nonprofits &amp; Activism</a>
  <a href="#">People &amp; Blogs</a>
  <a href="#">People &amp; Animals</a>
  <a href="#">Technology</a>
</div>
```

basically what I am trying to do is use the open button to both open the side navigation and also use the same button to close it if its open.

Comment: Where is your element with id `main`?

Comment: @dez sorry ignore that part, removing it from there rn

Comment: share a full code, where and when you are calling the function?

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry thought i had the part where I was calling it in there, just added it, its in the navigation

Comment: Can you please include the part where you bind `openNav` to an event listener?

Comment: `(x = true)` is **always true** because it does assign `true` to `x`, not **compare**. For comparison in Javascript, do ( x == true) or (x === true).

Comment: @connexo yea i saw that and fixed it in my code but still getting that error

Comment: @machineghost I included where I call openNav, its at the top in the topnav

Comment: please fix the typo in your code you posted here.

Comment: @RandyCasburn are you talking about the x==true? just fixed it !

Comment: Great - last thing. You need to set `x` back to true in the `else`. that is precisely why descriptive variable names are important. You should change `x` to `open` or something similar that makes sense to you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you ! after looking at it again i saw what was wrong and fixed it !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you're showing doesn't have that error you've mentioned. What it does mean is that `document.getElementById('mySidebar')` does not find any element with that `id` value in your HTML.

Aside from that, why your code example doesn't toggle:

You need to **invert** `x` **every** time the button is clicked. Currently you're setting it to `false` in the `if`-case, but never re-setting it to `true` in the `else`-case.

```js
var x = true;

function openNav() {
  if (x == true) {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  }
  x = !x;
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 250px;
  /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed;
  /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: ;
  /* 0 to Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidebar */
}
```

```html
<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Toggle Sidebar</button>
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Auto &amp; Vehicale</a>
  <a href="#">Beuty &amp; Fashion</a>
  <a href="#">Comedy</a>
  <a href="#">Education</a>
  <a href="#">Entertainment</a>
  <a href="#">Film &amp; Animation</a>
  <a href="#">Food</a>
  <a href="#">Gaming</a>
  <a href="#">How-To</a>
  <a href="#">Music</a>
  <a href="#">News &amp; Politics</a>
  <a href="#">Nonprofits &amp; Activism</a>
  <a href="#">People &amp; Blogs</a>
  <a href="#">People &amp; Animals</a>
  <a href="#">Technology</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this could be a solution; what possible value for `x`, right or wrong, could possibly cause an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"?  The only thing that could seem to cause that error is if `document.getElementById("mySidebar")` was `null`, and no value of `x` can make that happen.

Comment: @machineghost Your statement is correct. All I did in my answer is fix the code OP showed. Added clarification on that.

Comment: Well, your fix (for what was clearly bad logic) evidently led the OP to find the real source of his problem ... or else he just gave up and accepted your answer out of embarrassment :)  Either way it's great they found a solution, but it's too bad they didn't come back here with it: without OP reporting what the actual problem and solution was, no one else will get to benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally what's going on is the browser is failing to find the element with the ID "mySidebar" (thus the error "Cannot read property 'style' of null" ... when you try to access the `style` property of that element).  However, that element is clearly there in your HTML, and there's no issues with event hook-up timings because you're using an `onclick` attribute.

In other words, something doesn't add up.  All that's relevant here is:

```
<button onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Toggle Sidebar</button>
<div id="mySidebar" ></div>
```

and:

```
function openNav() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("mySidebar"));
}
```

If you just had that, you should see mySidebar get logged when you click your button, and if that happens then you shouldn't be getting errors about "Cannot read property 'style' of null" (referring to `document.getElementById("mySidebar")` being null).

If you do, there must be a typo or something we're not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `close` with `width: 0px`, You can use the classList property of the object to check if the object is closed or open by checking if it contains the class `close` or not.

```js
function openNav(){
  let a = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')
  if(a.classList.contains('close')){
    a.classList.remove('close')
  }else{
    a.classList.add('close')
  }
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 250px;
  /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed;
  /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: ;
  /* 0 to Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidebar */
}
.close{
 width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Toggle Sidebar</button>
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Auto &amp; Vehicale</a>
  <a href="#">Beuty &amp; Fashion</a>
  <a href="#">Comedy</a>
  <a href="#">Education</a>
  <a href="#">Entertainment</a>
  <a href="#">Film &amp; Animation</a>
  <a href="#">Food</a>
  <a href="#">Gaming</a>
  <a href="#">How-To</a>
  <a href="#">Music</a>
  <a href="#">News &amp; Politics</a>
  <a href="#">Nonprofits &amp; Activism</a>
  <a href="#">People &amp; Blogs</a>
  <a href="#">People &amp; Animals</a>
  <a href="#">Technology</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `classList.toggle('close')` to save the hassle of checking.

Comment: `function openNav() { mySidebar.classList.toggle('close') }` is a little shorter.